# Pandas copy() different columns from different dataframes to a new dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have 2 dataframes that are coming from 2 different Excel files. I want to extract some columns from one file and other columns from the second file to print a new dataframe with the copied columns.

I copied 2 columns from different dataframes (df1 and df2) but I get print only one of them (the last one) in df3. How can get all of them in the df3?

```
    import pandas as pd

    df1 = pd.read_csv('ASX_public_DB.csv', sep=';', skiprows=5)
    df2 = pd.read_excel('ASX_delisted_6months.xlsx')

    df3 = df1[['ticker_symbol']].copy()
    df3 = df2[['ASX code']].copy()

    print(df3)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are overwriting df3.

**Method-1:**

```py
   import pandas as pd

    df1 = pd.read_csv('ASX_public_DB.csv', sep=';', skiprows=5)
    df2 = pd.read_excel('ASX_delisted_6months.xlsx')

    df3 = df1[['ticker_symbol']].copy()
    df3['ASX code'] = df2[['ASX code']].copy()

    print(df3)
```

**Method-2:**

````py
    import pandas as pd

    df1 = pd.read_csv('ASX_public_DB.csv', sep=';', skiprows=5)
    df2 = pd.read_excel('ASX_delisted_6months.xlsx')

    df3 = pd.DataFrame()
    df3['ticker_symbol'] = df1['ticker_symbol'].copy()
    df3['ASX code'] = df2['ASX code'].copy()

    print(df3)
```
````

Comment: I see, thanks. I get anyway a warning: SettingWithCopyWarning: A value is trying to be set on a copy of a slice from a DataFrame. And also ASX code column is added at the end of the list and values are all printed in a single cell.

Comment: no, also with .copy() I get the same output as before.

Comment: Yes, it worked, thanks! So basically without [[]] it create a list, meanwhile with double [[]] it creates a dataframe?

Comment: Thank you! It's clear now.